# How to bring the most recent value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to know my organisation sectors. But my code brings all the codes the organisation had since it was insert on the system and grouping by the its tag.

The most accurate query I have so far is grouping the the updates by MAX, but I don't want all the registries.. just the most recent one.

**Expected Result: I need only the most recent value (B.Code), discarding all the other old B.Code values**

```
SELECT A.organisation_ref, A.name, A.block_level, B.code_type, B.code , MAX(B.update_timestamp)
FROM [TB1].[DBO].[ORG] AS A
INNER JOIN [TB2].[DBO].[CODE] AS B
ON A.organisation_ref = B.organisation_ref AND B.CountryID = '76'
WHERE B.code_type = '1005'
GROUP BY A.organisation_ref, A.name, A.block_level, B.code_type, B.code
ORDER BY A.organisation_ref ASC
```

Result so Far:

```
organisation_ref    organisation_name   block_level code_type   code    update_timestamp
1   contoso A   7   1005    IAC 2008-05-12 19:27:41.567
1   contoso A   7   1005    IAE 2015-03-30 20:51:20.693
1   contoso A   7   1005    IN  NULL
1   contoso A   7   1005    INE 2014-11-19 09:51:00.417
1   contoso A   7   1005    IQQ 2015-08-05 17:22:28.763
4   contoso B   0   1005    CUU 2011-10-25 11:34:58.420
4   contoso B   0   1005    DAB 2012-05-02 17:15:38.667
4   contoso B   0   1005    LLH 2015-10-08 08:25:43.260
```

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: And add a tag for the dbms used. (Perhaps <sql-server>?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply`:

```
SELECT o.organisation_ref, o.name, o.block_level, c.code_type, c.code 
FROM [TB1].[DBO].[ORG] o CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) c.*
      FROM [TB2].[DBO].[CODE] c
      WHERE c.organisation_ref = o.organisation_ref AND
            c.CountryID = '76' AND
            c.code_type = '1005'
      ORDER BY c.update_timestamp DESC
     ) c
ORDER BY o.organisation_ref ASC;
```

Notice that I fixed your table aliases so they are meaningful abbreviations for the tables, rather than meaningless arbitrary letters.

Also, if `CountryID` and `code_type` are strings, then the comparison to strings is fine.  Otherwise, drop the single quotes so numbers are compared to numbers.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the time.
I run the query but I had some errors..

    Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The multi-part identifier "c.organisation_ref" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
The multi-part identifier "c.CountryID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The multi-part identifier "c.code_type" could not be bound.
Msg 107, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
The column prefix 'c' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.
The multi-part identifier "c.update_timestamp" could not be bound.